# wp remote post getting a 404 error code

Tags: http-api

```
$info = array(
  'values' => array(
    'email' => 'email@email.com',
    'firstname' => "firstname",
    'lastname' => "lastname",
    'source' => "WEB",
  ),
);
$infoo=json_encode($info);
  $sf_auth = 'Bearer ' . $data['accessToken'];
  $finalUrl="https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:Web_Registrations/rows/GUID:7777";
  $result= wp_remote_post( $finalUrl, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $sf_auth,
        ),
    'body' => $infoo,
    'cookies' => array()
    )
  );
```

Trying to post it within wp but i am receiving message: Not Found and errorcode: 404

CAn anyone what i am doing wrong??

Comment: Are you sure the final url is correct?

Comment: yes its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the method to PUT & httpversion to 1.1